# How can I hide button using argument in xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

How can I hide contentview using binding.How to use binding in On platform argument? please check following screen shot for issue.

[image]

In screeen shot example like showjoin isvisible true. then it's fine. but showjoin is false then by default contentview is displayed because of in onflatform is true.

please help me too sort-out this issue

Comment: You must clarify better your problem. What do you want to do?

Comment: I want to hide contentview using binding in onplatform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you are wanting to do is hide the `ContentView` when your platform is `Android`, I would suggest using the `OnPlatform` in your xaml. Also, setting the `IsVisible` property of a ContentView **twice** won't work well usually.

Using your **xaml** from above:

```
<OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="View">
    <On Platform="iOS">
        <ContentView Margin="20,10,20,20" HeightRequest="40">
            <!-- Rest of ContentView code -->
        </ContentView>
    </On>

    <!-- You must specify an Android view -->
    <On Platform="Android">
        <!-- Use a simple boxview with height and width 0 to create an empty view -->
        <BoxView HeightRequest="0" WidthRequest="0" IsVisible="False"/>
    </On>
</OnPlatform>
```

This will only show the `ContentView` on your page when using **iOS** and nothing on **Android**.

Comment: how can i add multiple contentview in ios

Comment: In the `<On Platform="iOS">` section, use a StackLayout, Grid or some other Layout and place your items inside.

Answer (score 1):

a) Create one Boolean property in Viewmodel e.g. IsContentViewVisible

b) Bind this property to contentview IsVisible property e.g. IsVisible = "{Binding  IsContentViewVisible}", also make sure Raisepropertychanged event should be in place.

c)  As per your need you set the IsContentViewVisible property to False/true in your ViewModel

Comment: I want to hide contentview using binding in onplatform

Comment: I have alerady used in invisible property in xaml

Comment: i want two condition satisfy in xaml

Comment: I have updated the answers. Does that work for you ?

Answer (score 0):

The question is not all to clear... but if you want to avoid the XAML OnPlatform override ( because it is not using Binding ), you can delete it in XAML and just add the correct logic in your ShowJoinButton bool property.

You can check platform in code ( even in your ViewModel ) like so:

```
if(Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS) ...
```

If you still want to have everything in XAML, that is also possible of course.
You can use Binding inside `OnPlatform`, thing to take note is the type argument has to be `BindingBase`!

```
<OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="BindingBase" iOS="{Binding MyBool}" Android="{Binding MyBool}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code to write binding in ViewModel class

```
private const string ShowJoinButtonPropertyName = "ShowJoinButton";
private bool showJoinButton = false;
public bool ShowJoinButton
{
    get { return showJoinButton; }
    set { SetProperty(ref showJoinButton, value, ShowJoinButtonPropertyName); }
}
```

Wherever you want to hide/show you need to use the below code

```
if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android)
{
    ShowJoinButton = false;
}
else
{
    ShowJoinButton = true;
}
```

Hope it helps!